# ionic 3 deployment --release build much slower than --prod

Tags: android, angular, cordova, deployment, ionic3

There are several ways to build with ionic 3, which are not really explained in detail in the docs:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/

The start time of my app varies drastically with the different builds:

`ionic cordova run android --release`
-> app start time 8 seconds

`ionic cordova run android --prod`
-> app start time 3 seconds

`ionic cordova run android --prod --release`
-> app start time 8 seconds

Would there be any reason for me not to build with just --prod? And if yes, what could I do to make --prod --release faster? (8 seconds is a not acceptable start up time for my pretty lightweight app) Is it true that I won't be able to deploy to Google Play Store without the --release option?

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but did you find an answer to improve build times of ionic app? thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to differenciate between the two flags: `--release` is a flag used by the `cordova` CLI while `--prod` is a flag that is use by the `ionic` CLI. So what are those flags doing?

`--prod` is an alias for all of the following flags:

- `--optimizejs`
- `--minifycss`
- `--aot`
- `--minifyjs`

And is responsible for minifying and optimizing your `.js` bundle -> this is what makes your app startup faster because the browser needs to parse and interpret less code.

`--release` tells cordova it should build a optimized release `.apk` which you can sign and upload to Google-Play.

Comment: rigth now I undestand why i need the flags `--prod` and `--release` but there is some way to optimize the app start time of a release build ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer [**this doc**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/) to see the details.

This is needed for the app store `release` mode build:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

[image]